# Windows Phone Search box Tags on tapping search results

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Is there any library available for Windows Phone with the `tags` in a search box feature? So if I start typing `age`, the search box should predict `agent` and `agent smith` etc and on tapping the predicted results, the search box gets filled with the tags (example image attached). Handling events like, `backkeypress` highlights the tag and another `backkeypress` removes the tag etc. Predicting results is easy, what I am looking for is all the events handling for search box with tags. Any free/paid library for the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few AutoCompleteBoxes ([Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx), [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)), but the just work for one item. If you want more items, you need to create the control by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of third party controls are available but you should prefer to write your own control. I used http://wpfactb.codeplex.com/releases/view/42340 control but you have to customized it and bugs are there to be fixed .
So I will suggest you to get hint from this and write your own control.

Answer (score 0):

For something as specialized as this, I would write it myself. And XAML suits really well for such tasks.

One horizontal stackpanel with custom styled buttons being added, and one LongListSelector for the results.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to implement.

1. Set the InputScope in your textbox.
2. On typing , you will get the possible result.
3. When you tap on the respective suggestion, you will get the value.
4. Create a Grid or Stackpanel and create a ellipse which should hold the tag value.
5. On tap of the value, add the value inside the created ellipse.